# how to call jquery plugin function in angular 5

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular5

I am using jquery plugin in my application I have to initialize the plugin through ace.demo.init() 
how I can call this function in component class 
here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NavComponent} from "../../shared/module/navbar/nav/nav.component"
import {FooterComponent} from 
 "../../shared/module/footer/footer/footer.component"
import {SidebarComponent} from 
"../../shared/module/sidebar/sidebar/sidebar.component"
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }
 ngAfterViewInit() {

 this.doJqueryLoad();
} 
 ngOnInit() {
 }
 doJqueryLoad() {
console.log("here i want to call")
 ace.demo.init()    // <==== giving error (cant fine name ace)

 }
 }
```

Comment: Best what you can do - do not use jQuery at all.

Comment: its huge plugin it take my time tu built in angular @andrey.shedko

Comment: if you've correctly imported the js file for your plugin, you can just do as follows:  declare var ace: any;  (assuming ace is declared in your plugin)

Comment: oh nice @David. it works man  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David said I just declare ace as follows

```
declare var ace: any;
```

then it worked for me